# Windows defender quarantined a PHP file I have been working on and restore doesn't seem to work

Tags: windows-defender

*Windows defender* (*Security*) quarantined a PHP file I have been working on and restore doesn't work.
I was mapped into one of my servers and *Window Security* claimed that a text file I've been working (projects.php) on was a virus and quarantined it. This took me by surprise since I'm not in the habit of writing viruses and I don't think I could if I wanted to. Anyway, I saw this file in *Protection history* and selected the *Restore* option (and yes, I was very careful to select *Restore*). It gave me the notice that *This threat or app has been allowed and will not be remediated in the future* but the file was **NOT** returned to the location it was before it was quarantined. I looked up where quarantined files are kept (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Quarantine) and I did find some folders and what appears to be an encoded file with the same date/time that the quarantine happened. I assume this is the file I want. Is there any way to decode this?

I also tried a administrator command line option I found from the Windows Defender programs folder:

`mpcmdrun -restore -listall`

This command did show the projects.php file as quarantined but then I ran this

`mpcmdrun -restore -all`

This produced an error that there are no quarantined items.

I still can see the encoded? file in the %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Quarantine folder that has the same date/time that the file was quarantined. I'm hoping this can be manually decoded into my projects.php file but it's currently some kind of binary file `3C9ED6E7DC4FE0132570B6AC0C5D76293CAB6888`

Any help getting this file would be appreciated since this is a new development server I spun up and have not yet setup any backup for it so I've lost about a week of development (I accept responsibility for this oversight :-)

- My workstation is Windows 10 Pro, version 1909.
- The server I was mapped to is Windows Server 2012 R2 running as a VM in XCP-NG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem with `mpcmdrun -restore -all` command was that it was trying to restore to a mapped folder that it didn't have access to. This is odd because it had access enough to quarantine it but whatever. I found this suggestion on answers.microsoft.com

```
mpcmdrun -restore -All -Path C:\LocalRestorePath
```

That brought my file back.

Answer (score -1):

You can try one thing -

1. Turn off the real-time scanning of windows defender.
2. Go to the threat history and try to restore the file again.
3. Then add this file to the excluded files, by going into **Virus and Threat protection settings** there will be a option **Exclusions**.
4. After this you can turn on real-time scanning again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jeff - You really should not accept answers that do not solve your problem.  If you want to accept this answer, you are more than welcome to do so, but you are under no obligation to accept an answer.

Comment: I didn't mean to. I thought I was accepting my answer and didn't realize it had my answer above Ayushman's.